# Set of Jones polynomials as the knot varies

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, jones-polynomial

Is a characterization known for the set of Laurent polynomials arising as the Jones polynomial of some knot? More generally, is such a characterization known for any of the famous knot polynomials?

Comment: "...as the knot varies"?  Varies *how*?  If the variation is due to an ambient isotopy or the Reidemeister moves, then invariant polynomials are... well... invariant.

Comment: As the knot ranges over the set of all knots; I believe this is clear from the content of my question, if not from the title.

Comment: Not much is known about this in general. For the Kauffman polynomial, we proved that the coefficients satisfy a certain quadratic relation. https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00502  There are also relations between different polynomials. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2783128

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your question is open for the Jones polynomial. However, it is solved for the Alexander polynomial. On page 171 of Rolfsen's Knots and Links, the following theorem appears.

**Theorem.** Let $p(t)$ be any Laurent polynomial satisfying:

1. $p(1) = \pm 1$, and
2. $p(t)=p(t^{-1})$.

There exists a knot $K$ whose Alexander polynomial $\Delta_K(t)$ is $p(t)$.

It is well-known that the Alexander polynomial satisfies the above conditions. In the proof, Rolfsen shows how to explicitly construct a knot $K$ whose Alexander polynomial is a given Laurent polynomial $p(t)$ satisfying the conditions above.

Rolfsen gives the original reference of this result as

- Seifert, H.; [Über das Geschlecht von Knoten](https://eudml.org/doc/159739). Math. Ann. 110 (1935), no. 1, 571–592.

Comment: Thank you - even if the Jones polynomial question remains open, are you aware of any variant of Seifert's construction that produces many (if not all) Jones polynomials?

Comment: I think that not much is really known about how to produce knots with prescribed Jones polynomial. Manchon [arXiv:0201160](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201160) used a construction of Morton and Bae [arXiv:0012089](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201160) to construct prime knots whose Jones polynomials have prescribed extreme coefficients.